# React MUI add Cancel and Ok buttons to TimePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I am using `import TimePicker from '@mui/lab/TimePicker';` time picker, and I need ability to manually confirm or cancel the selection. In the [documentation](https://mui.com/api/time-picker/) I see `cancelText` and `okText` options, but there are no ability to show those buttons (`showToolbar` is not relevant). Maybe I missed something, could somebody please help me?
`

Answer (score 0):

nowiko
I had same issue, thats how i resolved it !!!

```
.css-1e6y48t-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root {
display: none !important;
}
```

Just add this class, this will hide whole div of buttons..